# how to prevent url navigation in ionic3

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic3

can anyone tell me how to prevent secure link  navigation using app.component for. Eg:- when user hit url like this http:// localhost:8888/#/login he get login screen (login HTML) after that user press login button screen navigate to user screen but when user manual ly  hit link like http:// localhost:8888/#/user, screen which user get is still same login but problem is that it call all user.ts file which I want to prevent if user not login not I m trying to achieve this through app

Answer (score 2):

You can use ionic's lifecycle functions like `ionViewCanEnter` to perform security check and prevent unauthorised navigation - [Source](https://devdactic.com/ionic-auth-guards)

Something like this in you User page:

```
ionViewCanEnter() {
    return this.authService.authenticated();
 }
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i want to know how I can do security check through app